# How to put bullets under breadcrumb timeline?

Tags: html, breadcrumbs, timeline

I'm trying to put some bullet points underneath a breadcrumb-style timeline, however I can't figure out how to do it. I have tried this:

```
    <h1>Sign-Up Instructions</h1>

<div id="crumbs">
    <ul>
    <li><a href="#1"><b>STEP 1:</b><br>Sign up and pay for<br>the options<br> you want</a></li>
    <br>
    <li> point here</li>
  </ul>
</div>
    <div id="crumbs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#2"><b>STEP 2:</b><br>Sign up for<br>online sessions<br>(held most weeks)</a>
    <li><a href="#3"><b>STEP 3:</b><br>Mock<br>OSCEs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4"><b>STEP 4<br>(OPTIONAL):</b><br>Attend private<br>tutoring</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

But it separates one part of the timeline from the rest. I would like the timeline to be together.

Here is the HTML code of the working timeline, without bullet points:

```
 <h1>Sign-Up Instructions</h1>

<div id="crumbs">
    <ul class= "point">
    <li><a href="#1"><b>STEP 1:</b><br>Sign up and pay for<br>the options<br> you want</a></li>
    <li><a href="#2"><b>STEP 2:</b><br>Sign up for<br>online sessions<br>(held most weeks)</a></li>
    <li><a href="#3"><b>STEP 3:</b><br>Mock<br>OSCEs</a></li>
    <li><a href="#4"><b>STEP 4<br>(OPTIONAL):</b><br>Attend private<br>tutoring</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

Can someone let me know how I would do this? Thanks.

Here is the CSS:

```
h1 {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    color: #4679bd;
    font-weight: 400;
    text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}

body {
    margin: 0px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    background: #f3f3f3;
  line-height:25px;
}

#crumbs {
    text-align: center;
  margin-left: em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}

#crumbs ul {
    list-style: none;
    display: inline-table;
   position: relative; 
}

#crumbs ul li {
    display: inline;
}

#crumbs ul li a {
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: 130px;
    background: #8bdbed;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 50px 0px 0 120px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
  line-height:25px;
}

#crumbs ul li a:after {
    content: "";
    border-top: 90px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
    border-left: 90px solid #8bdbed;
    position: absolute;
    right: -90px;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 1;
}

#crumbs ul li a:before {
    content: "";
    border-top: 90px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
    border-left: 90px solid #f3f3f3;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: 0;
}

#crumbs ul li:first-child a {
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}

#crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
    display: none;
}

#crumbs ul li:last-child a {
    padding-right: 30px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}

#crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
    display: none;
}

/* Responsive */

@media (max-width: 1100px) {

    #crumbs ul {
        display: block;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;

    }

    #crumbs ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #crumbs ul li a {
        float: none;
        padding: 20px 0 0 0;
        margin: 0 0 5px 0; 
    }

    #crumbs ul li a:before, #crumbs ul li a:after {
        border-top: 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-left: 0;
    }

    #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
        border-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    }

    #crumbs ul li:last-child a {
        border-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
        padding-right: 0;
    }

  /*Max width for smaller screen size*/
  @media (max-width: 700px) {

    #crumbs ul {
        display: block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 10%;
    }

    #crumbs ul li {
        display: block;
        width: 100%;
    }

    #crumbs ul li a {
        float: none;
        padding: 10px 0 0 0;
        margin: 0 0 5px 0; 
    }

    #crumbs ul li a:before, #crumbs ul li a:after {
        border-top: 0;
        border-bottom: 0;
        border-left: 0;
    }

    #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
        border-radius: 0;
        border-top-left-radius: 10px;
        border-top-right-radius: 10px;
    }

    #crumbs ul li:last-child a {
        border-radius: 0;
        border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
        border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    }

}
```

Comment: It would be easier if you added the CSS in a [mcve]. Is this timeline horizontal?

Comment: I'll post the CSS. Yes, it's horizontal.

Comment: Your HTML in the first example is invalid. You cannot put a `<br>` element in between `<li>` elements.

Answer (score 0):

I think that put another unsorted list inside of the items, may be what you are looking for:

```html
<h1>Sign-Up Instructions</h1>
  <div id="crumbs">
    <ul class="point">
      <li>
        <a href="#1"><b>STEP 1:</b></a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#1">Sign up and pay for<br>the options<br> you want</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#2"><b>STEP 2:</b></a>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="#2">Sign up for<br>online sessions<br>(held most weeks)</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      ...
    </ul>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

May be below code will help! I have removed media queries form styles to avoid complexity.
There

- I have added a nested ul within the main ul list items.
- Added a CSS class named "test" to the nested ul. Use a proper name to the class accordingly.
- Break the style inheritance from the parent ul by adding !important
- Add the styles to make it as a usual unorderd list

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #4679bd;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#crumbs {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
#crumbs ul {
  display: inline-table;
  position: relative;
}
#crumbs ul li {
  display: inline;
}
ul.test {
  float: left;
  margin-top: 200px;
  margin-left: -150px;
}
ul.test li {
  list-style: square!important;
  display: block!important;
  display: list-item!important;
}
#crumbs ul li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 130px;
  background: #8bdbed;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0px 0 120px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#crumbs ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid #8bdbed;
  position: absolute;
  right: -90px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#crumbs ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid #f3f3f3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
  display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a {
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="crumbs">
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li class="">
      <a href="#1"><b>STEP 1:</b><br>Sign up and pay for<br>the options<br> you want</a>
      <ul class="test">
        <li>1st point here</li>

        <li>2nd point here</li>

        <li>3rd point here</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li></li>
    <li class="">
      <a href="#2"><b>STEP 2:</b><br>Sign up for<br>online sessions<br>(held most weeks)</a>
      <ul class="test">
        <li>1st point here</li>

        <li>2nd point here</li>

        <li>3rd point here</li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class=""><a href="#3"><b>STEP 3:</b><br>Mock<br>OSCEs</a>
    </li>

    <li class=""><a href="#4"><b>STEP 4<br>(OPTIONAL):</b><br>Attend private<br>tutoring</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/buddhirameshi/m2z9wcro/#&togetherjs=bVVr1THps2)

Comment: I have edited the answer in accordance with the latter styles you have provided. Hope it'll help

Comment: Thank you! That worked, but when the screen size is smaller the bullet points get messed up... they don't work with the responsiveness of the timeline. Do you know how I can fix this?

Comment: The reason is I have not added styles for responsive pages. You can adjust the margins of the bullet points to be compatible with the responsive pages inside media queries.

Answer (score 0):

Add this ruleset to CSS:

> ```
> .bullet {
>   font-size: 50px;
>   color: #000;
>   text-align: center;
>   margin: 20px auto;
> }
> ```

and add this above and under each `<li>`:

> ```
> <li class='bullet'>∗</li>
> ```

<kbd>[**PLUNKER**](http://embed.plnkr.co/TDM4fDkRJEH52YNDpOgc/)</kbd>

#### SNIPPET

```css
h1 {
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  color: #4679bd;
  font-weight: 400;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: Verdana, Geneva, sans-serif;
}
body {
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: Helvetica;
  background: #f3f3f3;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#crumbs {
  text-align: center;
  margin-left: 1em;
  margin-right: 1em;
}
#crumbs ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: inline-table;
  position: relative;
}
#crumbs ul li {
  display: inline;
}
#crumbs ul li a {
  display: block;
  float: left;
  height: 130px;
  background: #8bdbed;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 50px 0 0 120px;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 10px 0 0;
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
  line-height: 25px;
}
#crumbs ul li a:after {
  content: "";
  border-top: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid #8bdbed;
  position: absolute;
  right: -90px;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 1;
}
#crumbs ul li a:before {
  content: "";
  border-top: 90px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 90px solid transparent;
  border-left: 90px solid #f3f3f3;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a {
  border-top-left-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
  padding-left: 20px;
}
#crumbs ul li:first-child a:before {
  display: none;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a {
  padding-right: 30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
}
#crumbs ul li:last-child a:after {
  display: none;
}
.bullet {
  font-size: 50px;
  color: #000;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 20px auto;
}
/* Responsive */

@media (max-width: 1100px) {
  #crumbs ul {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 20%;
    margin-right: 20%;
  }
  #crumbs ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #crumbs ul li a {
    float: none;
    padding: 20px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li a:before,
  #crumbs ul li a:after {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
    padding-right: 0;
  }
}
/*Max width for smaller screen size*/

@media(max-width: 700px) {
  #crumbs ul {
    display: block;
    margin-left: 5%;
    margin-right: 10%;
  }
  #crumbs ul li {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #crumbs ul li a {
    float: none;
    padding: 10px 0 0 0;
    margin: 0 0 5px 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li a:before,
  #crumbs ul li a:after {
    border-top: 0;
    border-bottom: 0;
    border-left: 0;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:first-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-top-left-radius: 10px;
    border-top-right-radius: 10px;
  }
  #crumbs ul li:last-child a {
    border-radius: 0;
    border-bottom-left-radius: 10px;
    border-bottom-right-radius: 10px;
  }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Sign-Up Instructions</h1>

  <div id="crumbs">
    <ul>
      <li class='bullet'>∗</li>
      <li><a href="#1"><b>STEP 1:</b><br>Sign up and pay for<br>the options<br> you want</a>
      </li>
      <li class='bullet'>∗</li>
      <li><a href="#2"><b>STEP 2:</b><br>Sign up for<br>online sessions<br>(held most weeks)</a>
      </li>
      <li class='bullet'>∗</li>
      <li><a href="#3"><b>STEP 3:</b><br>Mock<br>OSCEs</a>
      </li>
      <li class='bullet'>∗</li>
      <li><a href="#4"><b>STEP 4<br>(OPTIONAL):</b><br>Attend private<br>tutoring</a>
      </li>
      <li class='bullet'>∗</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```